# Left Join to another table and to same table for checking whether member exisits or not causing it to break

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, query-performance

I have an interesting and challenging question to solve .

I have a table X with 3 columns name, id, parent (parent is self referencing to same table) and this has 1 million records with no parent records ( all records with parent column is null)

I have another temporary table ( stage) with same structure with 1 million records with parent column also .

now, I want to insert this stage into original tableX, but before that perform a left join with itself and also this with Y to check if there is any member already exists or not ( to avoid duplicate inserts into it) . the below select query output is inserted into another table so I avoid pasting it .

here is my query :

```
`SELECT stg.code, stg.id, stg.parent
FROM Stage stgl
LEFT JOIN TableX dm -- First see if the member already exists
ON stgl.[Parent] = dm.Code
AND dm.Status_ID = 1 -- Active
AND dm.Version_ID = @Version_ID
LEFT JOIN Stage dm2 -- Same stage table as above 
ON stgl.[Parent] = dm2.Code`
```

this is a never ending query when testing with 2 million records and SSMS keeps on running for more than 3 hours .

I need someone to please check this and help me with suitable answer or probably best way of re-writing this query

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the query per se, except that you might not be using any indices.  Do you have an index on any of the join columns?

Comment: No Tim I cannot use the index here on the self referential column , this will have a performance hit during inserts . correct me if I am wrong .

Comment: You can't have it both ways.  How often do you plan on inserting vs. querying?

Comment: Every time user will be staging millions of records as one single batch and can go upto running 10 plus batches on a given single day . so every time I have to make sure no record is a duplicate record within the batch as well as already in the table .

Comment: Maybe one unique index on all columns making a record unique would actually speed up inserting then?

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS`, it stops as soon as the condition is met:

```
SELECT stg1.code, stg1.id, stg1.parent
FROM Stage stg1
where exists (
    select 1 
    from TableX dm 
    where stgl.[Parent] = dm.Code
    AND dm.Status_ID = 1 -- Active
    AND dm.Version_ID = @Version_ID
    )
and exists (
    select 1
    from Stage dm2 -- Same stage table as above 
    where stgl.[Parent] = dm2.Code
    )
```

Comment: That's the fastest reply john , let me do a quick dry run with 10Million records and see .

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to get records from TableX in other table as below and then use that table in INNER join

```
DECLARE @tblX AS Table
(
    Code VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @tblX
SELECT 
    Code
FROM TableX
WHERE Version_ID=@Version_ID
AND Status_ID=1

SELECT stgl.code, stgl.id, stgl.parent
FROM Stage stgl
INNER JOIN @tblX dm -- First see if the member already exists
ON stgl.[Parent] = dm.Code
INNER JOIN Stage dm2 -- Same stage table as above 
ON dm.Code = dm2.Code
```

Comment: Thanks Sandip, I tried this before and was not successful . have you tried in this way?

Comment: I have tried in past and give better performance then where condition in join, I haven't your data, so I haven't test now

Comment: good point sandip , for benefit of others I will give some sample data quickly on how to generate million records . I will edit my question thanks for pointing it out .